# DevTools: referencing a Vue file from multiple sourcemaps

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

When compiling vue single file components with `webpack / vue-loader` that contain plain CSS/JS/HTML, i end up with two sourcemaps: `bundle.css.map` and `bundle.js.map` (I'm using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to separate out the CSS). The JS/CSS sourcemaps both source the same vue file with identical path values e.g.

```js
// bundle.css.map
{"version": 3, "sources": ["webpack:///header.vue", ...}
```

After adding a Workspace in Chrome DevTools, when I click through to the Vue file from a JavaScript console reference, I'm redirected successfully to the mapped `header.vue` file:

[image]

[image]

But now when I try to access the vue file from a CSS declaration on the styles pane, i'm redirected unsuccessfully to an unlinked file source:

[image]

[image]

Repository mocking the issue: https://github.com/Boycce/devtools-issue

*#whatamigonnado*

Comment: Do you have a URL where I can repro?

Comment: Hey @KayceBasques, I have just updated the question with a repository link.